# Selenium: how to find element by text

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to search element by text with selenium but didn't find anything that work. The element is displayed below:

`<div class="slick-cell l0 r0 project"><span class="project-name"><a href="/reports.htm#p10075">MFIT</a></span></div>`

There are multiple elements of this type so I need to find this element by `MFIT` and return the href.

I've tried multiples possibilities using XPath which didn't work.

- `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@*, 'MFIT')]")` and go over the list
- `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@*, 'MFIT')]")`
- `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='project-name' and contains(., 'MFIT')]")`

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Add your whole code and url. Try this one **//*[contains(text(), 'MFIT')]**

Comment: got another element that contains **MFIT** but not this one. tried this syntax with ```find_elements``` but same

Comment: add url and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), 'MFIT')]").get_attribute('href')


WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), 'MFIT')]")))
```

#imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Got an error **Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(text(), 'MFIT')]"}**

Comment: You need to use WebDriverWait

Comment: Works !! Thanks !
Can you explain me why it's works ?

Comment: One of the biggest reasons  throwing `Unable to locate element:` is the absence of load time